# RSVP Module not obeying default status

Tags: add-on, safecracker, module

I'm using the [RSVP Module](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/rsvp) with a site and it is great, but despite its default being set to "enabled", new entries always have it disabled.

I'd like to know, at the least, what I can hook into in the module's code to view what is happening when the entry is being created (through safecracker).

When publishing an entry through the admin panel, this feature does work as expected, so I'm kind of geared towards writing a safecracker hook, but I could really use some direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with the solution.
After the entry has been submitted, hook into safecracker and insert an rsvp entry for the id.

```
public function safecracker_submit_entry_end( &$safecracker ) {
// Verify this only runs where it should.
if(  ! $this->_inEventScope() ) {
    return false;
}

$entryID = $safecracker->entry('entry_id');

if( isset( $entryID ) && !empty( $entryID ) ) {

    $data = array(
        'entry_id' => $entryID,
        'total_seats' => 0
    );

    $query = $this->EE->db->insert( 'exp_cm_rsvp_events', $data );
}
```

}